# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require(37 ).PropTypes.shape')

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm getting this error after upgrading Expo from version 21 to 24.

It seems like I have a problem with `PropTypes`.

From Expo v22.0.0, the author warned that

> If you, or any libraries that you use. use View.propTypes.style you
>   will need to change that to ViewPropTypes.style. You will only see
>   errors for this in production — so be sure to test your app with
>   development mode disabled.

But I haven't used PropTypes in my react native code BUT I guess there is a function in SnackBar has `PropTypes` and I have to update them to use it.

How can I solve this? The error is saying there is something wrong with Snackbar.js code but I don't understand...

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'require(37     ).PropTypes.shape') <unknown>
    type.js:1:126 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:191:12 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:138:36
_require
    require.js:118:20 <unknown>
    SnackBar.js:8:1003 loadModuleImplementation <<<<
    require.js:191:12 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:138:36
_require
    require.js:118:20 <unknown>
    SnackBarManager.js:5:22 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:191:12 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:138:36
_require
    require.js:118:20 <unknown>
    index.js:1:86 loadModuleImplementation
    require.js:191:12 guardedLoadModule
    require.js:138:36
...
```

I confirmed that `snackbar.js` doesn't have `PropTypes`.

SnackBar is open source : `react-native-snackbar-dialog`

**This happens to other packages too. moments.js and more. The upgrade break the whole dependency and I can't figure out what I've done wrong**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd node_modules/react-native-snackbar-dialog && yarn build` solved my issue.

Same for other thing packages.